# Metronome on Yamaha CP-50 stage piano

Tags: rhythm, digital-piano, metronomes

I have a Yamaha CP-50 stage piano and I was unable to find a metronome function. Surely metronome is not one of the preset drum settings. Does anyboy know an easy way how to start a metronome on this device?

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments here. Summary: Erring on the respectful side is good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual it seems like you need to be recording in order to use the metronome.  You could try this part, but it's step 4 of the recording process:

> Press the [PAGE ►], [3], or [4] button to navigate to Pages 3 and 4 of the Record screen, and then turn Knobs 1 to 3 to set the tempo, time signature, and metronome for recording.

If that doesn't work check out the owner's manual and try the whole process — it's on the Support tab of [this page](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/music-production/stagepianos/cp/cp50/?mode=model/).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this marked community wiki?

Comment: @Luke The suggestion to look in the owner's manual came from another answer that has been deleted, I didn't want to get rep for something I didn't put the work into finding :)

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't think it was necessary to make it CW, but it's your choice ;) Anyways, thanks for this, I have found it in between in the Reference Manual. However, I'm not happy with this solution, since it's pretty stupid and complicated, so I might see, maybe someone has a "metronome" drum file for CP-50...